# GWT Column turn off word wrap

Tags: gwt, formatting, word-wrap

I am using a Gwt DataGrid with multiple Columns.  The default behavior of the columns is to wordwrap.  I would like for one of the columns to not wordwrap and just cut off.  Is this possible?

For example, currently this is displayed:

```
I am making a
sandwich
```

I would like it to display:

```
I am making a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `overflow:hidden` you may need `white-space:nowrap` and finally add a `text-overflow: ellipsis` so there is an indicator to the user that the incomplete text is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `overflow: hidden` in the style of each Column.

You can use `DataGrid.addColumnStyleName` to set styles on individual columns, or just `addStyleName` to add a style to the whole widget.